# Any one knows how to upload file from ASP.net to remote rest service ( not WCF)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I need to implement upload method in ASP.net c# to upload file to remote rest service instead uploading it to my local machine.

I have wrote a function that posts data to the rest service now I want to know how to post the file stream to the rest service ?

I am using the following lines of code to post the data

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
{
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(PostData);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

know how to make postData is my file stream ? instead of string.

Comment: Send it to your server and from your server send it to the REST service with an HttpWebRequest

Comment: What happens when you try this code?

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have use this technique:

```
private static StreamContent CreateFileContent(Stream fileStream, string fileName, string contentType)
{
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "\"files\"",
        FileName = "\"" + fileName + "\""
    }; // the extra quotes are key here

    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

    return fileContent;
}
```

And then an upload via a `HttpClient` like this:

```
private async Task UploadFile(HttpClient client, Stream fileStream, string filename)
{
    //HttpClient initialized by caller
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        //file contains XML
        content.Add(CreateFileContent(fileStream, filename, "text/xml"));
        var resp = await client.PostAsync("the/rest/endpoint", content);
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    return;
    // Error handling left as an exercise for the reader.
}
```

Comment: You should be ashamed of yourself for the `catch{throw;}`

Comment: @JohnSaunders Is that better?  Error handling was removed for brevity.

Comment: We get too many developers here who only know how to copy/paste. I'd get rid of the try/catch block entirely and "leave it as an exercise for the reader".